# Shell Script To Notify When Server Uptime Has Reached Threshold

Tags: linux, shell, uptime

I'm looking to cleanup the following shell script that reads in the uptime of a Linux server and will mail a certain user when the threshold has been met so that we know when to reboot through a daily cron job. The below will read in the uptime and output the result to a file, which will then be emailed. I'd also like to add in the hostname of the server either the report or the email heading. Fairly new to shell scripting so any/all tips are appreciated. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
timeup () { uptime | awk  '{print $3}'; }
UPTIME=100
if [ $(timeup) -ge $UPTIME ]; then

    #output uptime to report
    uptime | awk '{print $3,$4}' | sed 's/,//' >> /opt/scripts/report.out 

    #mail report 
    cat /opt/scripts/report.out | mail -s "Server Needs To Be Rebooted" "your@emailaddress.com"

    #remove old file
    rm -f /opt/scripts/report.out   
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`timeup () { uptime | awk  '{print $3}'; }` result will be something like that: "**45:45,**". There are 2 problems with this:

- return value will be string instead of integer therefore **if** line will send an error message
- "," sign at the and of the string

This is better (but not so nice :) ):
`timeup () { uptime | awk  '{print $3}' | awk -F\: '{print $1}';}`

Second awk command divide hour and minute, and print only hours.

I prefer sendEmail script instead of mail command: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sendEmail.1.html

I'd put hostname in the subject: `"Server Needs To Be Rebooted: $(hostname -f)"`

`hostname -f` command print out FQDN

You can merge **uptime ...** and **mail** command lines and remove **rm** command:

`uptime | awk '{print $3,$4}' | sed 's/,//' |  mail -s "Server Needs To Be Rebooted" "your@emailaddress.com"`